# Issue in understanding void pointer statement

Tags: c

I am searching for a MODBUS lib. And I found one, but I not able to understand what is this macro doing AND what this mean

```
#define __UNUSED(x)     ( ( void ) ( (x) == (x) ) ) //what this macro doing**


int
target_initialise( void * Target ) {

    __UNUSED( Target );

    return 0;
}


void *
target_alloc( void * Target, unsigned int Bytes ) {

    __UNUSED( Target );
    __UNUSED( Bytes );

    return NULL;
}


void
target_free( void * Target, void * Data ) {

    __UNUSED( Target );
    __UNUSED( Data );
}
```

Comment: which library are you using? I had good experience with [libmodbus](http://libmodbus.org/)

Comment: This looks like placeholder code. That is, the functions do nothing, they are to be replaced with functional code later or in some other circumstance, and the `__UNUSED` macro is used to prevent the compiler from complaining that the parameters are not used. Or it may be the functions must be defined for some reason, but they are not actually needed in this version of the driver, so they are trivial implementations.

Answer (score 1):

The macro expands to

```
int
target_initialise( void * Target ) {

    (void) (Target == Target);

    return 0;
}
```

and it's used to silence compiler warnings. If you for example compile with
with gcc and use `-Wall`, then the compiler warns about a lot of things, for
example unused variables. So in `target_initialise` the variable `Target` is
not used and the compiler would warn about that, but using the macro the
compiler would remain silent.

I have no idea why the code is doing that.